# Java - Object storing a reference to another object

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I have to create an array of 5 objects in which some objects *hold a reference* to another object in the array.

Is this as simple as creating the objects and using, for example, **a[0] = a[1]**, or am I severely underestimating what's being asked?

Comment: Assuming your explanation of the task is accurate, you need the *objects* to hold references to each other - not just for the array to hold references to the objects.

Comment: a[0] = yourObject;  → a[1] = a[0];  → a[0] and a[1] will be pointing to the same object (yourObject)

Comment: An object can only hold a reference to another object if it has a reference-type *field*. As such, you need to create a custom class for this assignment.

Comment: So the answer is *no* it’s not that simple and *yes* you have underestimated what needs to be done

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking the wrong way. You can achieve this using classes.

**Your class**

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass otherClass;

    public MyClass() {otherClass = null;}

    public MyClass(MyClass otherClass) {this.otherClass = otherClass;}
}
```

**Now, you can also maintain these classes in an array.**

```
MyClass classes[] = new MyClass[size];
```

**And create relations...**

```
classes[0].otherClass = classes[1];
```

**But please keep in mind that the statement below will basically override your class pointer**

```
classes[0] = classes[1] // now both classes are pointing to the same memory.
```

Concepts like these are used in DataStructures like `LinkedList`, `Trees` and `Graphs`.